# Trouble installing WebOrb on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, weborb

I'm trying to evaluate the weborb integration product, but I'm having troubles getting it setup for ASP.NET. The installation appears to complete successfully, but when I go to run the weborb console I get a series of errors.

I found some documentation on WebOrb's site about installing WebOrb for IIS 7.

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/developer-den/technical-articles/weborb-vista7-installation.html

It said I needed to run the command "appcmd migrate config 'Default Web Site/weborb4'".

When I do this, I get the error: "ERROR ( message:Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique 'name' set to 'weborb.aspx_*' )

I also installed all the extra IIS components (IIS 6 too) that WebOrb suggested installing.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

-- FOUND SOLUTION --

While I'm not sure what caused the above error (I'm new to this IIS admin stuff), I was able to get the WebOrb installation to work correctly, which didn't require the above command. The above migration probably wasn't necessary due to the fix I implemented to get the WebOrb console to load correctly. After extensive searching, I was able to find this WebOrb posting:

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=3591

The fix was to run:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

which registered .NET 4.0 on my IIS, even .NE 4.0 was already installed. It was defaulting to .NET 2.0.

Now it runs great.

Comment: @user361870 (you might want to choose a nickname): If you found a solution please remove it from your *question* but post it as an *answer* and accept it using the checkmark icon next to it.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to post anything other than a comment to this post anymore. I'd like to post my solution and check it, like you recommended.

Comment: you can click the "answer your question" button below the big **Know someone who can answer?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- FOUND SOLUTION --

While I'm not sure what caused the above error (I'm new to this IIS admin stuff), I was able to get the WebOrb installation to work correctly, which didn't require the above command. The above migration probably wasn't necessary due to the fix I implemented to get the WebOrb console to load correctly. After extensive searching, I was able to find this WebOrb posting:

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=3591

The fix was to run:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

which registered .NET 4.0 on my IIS, even .NE 4.0 was already installed. It was defaulting to .NET 2.0.

Now it runs great.

Comment: This is not working for me ((((( I'm trying everything here but without success.

Comment: Can you give some details to your IIS Conifugration?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122994/weborb5-installation-in-visual-studio2013-project]