# WebORB5 installation in Visual Studio2013 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache-flex, flex4, weborb

I'm trying to install a WebORB in a testing new ASP.NET4.5 Project visual Studio2013. I'm using this manual [WebORB4Net.pdf](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v5/WebORB4Net.pdf), Ref 6.1 Installation From Zip, 6.3-Installing WebORB into existing ASP.NET application.
But when I'm try to surf to this directory `http://localhost/MediaServer/weborbconsole.html`, i'm getting this error

1. First error screen : Server reported an error: Send failed
2. second screen clicking on Ok : SECURITY:Send failed
3. Third: SERVICES:

   - faultString:'Send failed'
   - faultDetail:'Channel.Security. Error error
   - Error #2048 url: `https://mylocalhost/MediaServer/console/weborb.aspx`
   - SECURITY:Send failed

We never used this Server, I was asking to try it to know if we can use it our project.

Any help ?

### Update for comment

[image: Project structure and IIS Site structure]

Comment: Can you tell us what the directory structure of your VS2013 project looks like as well as the directory structure of your IIS website?

Comment: Also, you might try experimenting w/ an indepedent install of WebOrb before you start altering your ASP.NET project. You can just add a new Application to "MyLocalHost", like "WebOrb" for instance and unzip the WebORB-5.1.0.0.zip into that new application. Then you should be able to navigate to it (i.e.; http://mylocalhost/WebOrb/weborbconsole.html)

Comment: @StoneJedi, As independent server, it works and show me the Administration interface. i also try to use code generation for chat and copy code to flash builder, and my webcam start well and show video. But when i'm trying to use the installation in ASP.NET Project nothing is working ! Or may be there are better way to do this ! I want to buit a video Chat application. I already have a social network but i want to integrate a video call for users functionality inside. May be i'm not using the best scenario for this task. Any ideas ?

Comment: I really don't know enough about WebOrb to speak for it's use in a Real Time Video Communication application. It very well could be a great option, I just don't know enough about it's use in that arena. I'm not sure what your browser support requirements are, but have you looked at using WebRTC: http://www.webrtc.org/. Looks like no IE support or you might need to use some workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724913/which-version-of-microsoft-internet-explorer-support-webrtc.

Comment: I do see some examples utilizing SignalR and OpenTok. http://geekswithblogs.net/duresameen/archive/2014/07/31/day-3-summary--live-video-chat--opentok-signalr.aspx